# HTML input types does not display correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, radio-button

This is the code that I've used, but I don't think it is something wrong with the code, as it works well in Safari but not Chrome.[The left hand is Chrome and the other is Safari. As you can see, the radio, submit, reset type somehow disappeared in Chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTlBw.png)

[Check out this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Iga.png) Normally there should be various checkboxes that I can select on or off. But in my browser it doesn't work.

```
 <form method="GET">
         <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male <br>
         <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female <br>
         <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other <br>
         Pets <br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="dog" value=""> Dogs<br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="cat" value=""> Cats<br>
         Cars <br>
         <select class="" name="cars">
           <option value="volvo" name="volvo">Volvo</option>
           <option value="Audi" name="audi">Audi</option>
         </select><br>
         <input type="submit" name="" value="Register">
         <input type="reset" name="" value="Reset">
    </form>
```

Comment: It works well.no any issue in chrome.

Comment: It works fine on my friend's chrome as well, but I kept having this problem. See the screenshoot that I provided above. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTlBw.png

Comment: What version of OS are you using?  Chrome doesn't support 10.14 yet.  crbug.com/850021

Comment: You got it right, I am using 10.14. Any idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` selectors

```html
<input type="submit" name="" value="Register">
<input type="reset" name="" value="Reset">
```

should be stated as buttons. Chrome wants them to be explicitly declared as `<button>`.

```html
<button type="submit">Register</button>
<button type="reset">Reset</button>
```

Here's an improved version of your provided code with some fixes. You can follow how to properly structure a `<form>` [via MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form).

```html
<form method="GET">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="male"><label for="male">Male</label> <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="female"><label for="female">Female</label> <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" id="other"><label for="other">Other</label> <br> Pets <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="dog" value="" id="dogs"><label for="dogs">Dogs</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="" id="cats"><label for="cats">Cats</label>
  <br> Cars <br>
  <select class="" name="cars">
    <option value="volvo" name="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="Audi" name="audi">Audi</option>
  </select><br>
  <button type="submit">Register</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: nope, it doesn't solve the problem. As you can see in the screenshoot provided above, my code actually runs quite well in Safari. The input type "radio" doesn't shown in Chrome at all.

Comment: @XiaoyunZhi Can you show the rest of your code? I think it has to do with some CSS and `appearance`, but I can't judge on solely these screenshots.

Comment: I don't have a css file for them.

Comment: Sorry about that, I deleted some of the irrelevant code. I edited the question, and it's clear something wrong about my browser rather than the code. I cannot see the radios on other websites either.